# TKCalendarMonthTableViewController in tab bar view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, calendar

TapkuLibrary is an open source iOS framework built on Cocoa and UIKit intended for broad use in applications. I am attempting to use the TKCalendarMonthTableViewController to immitate a calendar in my app. I checked out their demo app and they do NOT use .nib files, so it is all programmically.

I am attempting to use this view in a tab bar application. Interface builder dosnt allow you to select TKCalendarMonthTableViewController as a class.

From my understanding this should work

```
UIViewController *vc;
vc = [[Calendar alloc] initWithSunday:NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
[vc release];
```

But where should I call this code, if this is correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the calendar on one of the tabs then you need to create the Calendar view controller and then provide it to your UITabBarController as part of its viewControllers array. (See viewControllers property documentation for UITabBarController).

The code you have listed above would be used to present the calendar in response to a button tap that would result in the calender being shown on top of the current view controller's view.